# Upload file using python requests

Tags: box-api, python-requests

I've been trying to upload a file using the box v2 api with requests.

So far I had little luck though. Maybe someone here can help me see what I'm actually doing wrong.

```
file_name = "%s%s" % (slugify(sync_file.description), file_suffix)
file_handle = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + str(sync_file.document), 'rb')
folder_id = str(sync_file.patient.box_patient_folder_id)

r = requests.post(
    files_url,
    headers=headers,
    files={
        file_name: file_handle,
        "folder_id": folder_id,
    },
)
```

My authentication works, because I'm creating a folder just before that, using the same data.

A response looks something like this:

```
{
    u'status': 404, 
    u'code': u'not_found', 
    u'help_url': u'http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors', 
    u'request_id': u'77019510950608f791a0c1', 
    u'message': u'Not Found', 
    u'type': u'error'
}
```

Maybe someone on here ran into a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone requested my implementation, I figured I would put it out here for anyone trying to achieve something similar.

```
files_url = "%s/files/content" % (settings.BOX_API_HOST)
headers = {"Authorization": "BoxAuth api_key=%s&auth_token=%s" % 
              (settings.BOX_API_KEY, self.doctor.box_auth_token)
          }

file_root, file_suffix = os.path.splitext(str(self.document))
filename = "%s%s" % (slugify(self.description), file_suffix)
files = {
        'filename1': open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + str(self.document), 'rb'),
        }
data = {
        'filename1': filename,
        'folder_id': str(self.patient.get_box_folder()),
       }

r = requests.post(files_url,
                  headers=headers,
                  files=files,
                  data=data)

file_response = simplejson.loads(r.text)

try:
    if int(file_response['entries'][0]['id']) > 0:
        box_file_id = int(file_response['entries'][0]['id'])

        #Update the name of file
        file_update_url = "%s/files/%s" % (settings.BOX_API_HOST, box_file_id) 
        data_update = {"name":  filename}
        file_update = requests.put(file_update_url,
                                   data=simplejson.dumps(data_update),
                                   headers=headers)

        LocalDocument.objects.filter(id=self.id).update(box_file_id=box_file_id)
except:
    pass
```

So in essence, I needed to send the file and retrieve the ID of the newly updated file and send another request to box. Personally, I don't like it either, but it works for me and haven't been able to find any other implementations that do the correct naming from the get-go.

Hope someone can benefit from this snippet.

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass 2 Python dictionaries, files and data. files are `{uniqFileName:openFileObj}`, and data are `{uniqFileName:filename}`.  Below is the upload method from my box class.  And remember to add a final entry in data, `'folder_id': destination_id`.

```python
def uploadFiles(self, ufiles, folid):
    '''uploads 1 or more files in the ufiles list of tuples containing
    (src fullpath, dest name). folid is the id of the folder to
    upload to.'''

    furl = URL2 + 'files/data'
    data, files = {}, {}
    for i, v in enumerate(ufiles):
        ff = v[0]
        fn = v[1]
        #copy to new, renamed file in tmp folder if necessary
        #can't find a way to do this with the api
        if os.path.basename(ff) != fn:
            dest = os.path.join(TMP, fn)
            shutil.copy2(ff, dest)
            ff = dest

        f = open(ff, 'rb')
        k = 'filename' + str(i)
        data[k] = fn
        files[k] = f

    data['folder_id'] = folid

    res = self.session.post(furl, files=files, data=data)

    for k in files:
        files[k].close()


    return res.status_code
```

Here is a sample call:

```
destFol = '406600304'

ret = box.uploadFile((('c:/1temp/hc.zip', 'hz.zip'),), destFol)
```

Like I said, the above function is a method of a class, with an instance attr that holds a requests session.  But you can use `requests.post` instead of `self.session.post`, and it will work just the same.  Just remember to add the headers with your apikey and token if you do it outside a session.

According to the documentation, you are supposed to be able to rename the file by giving it a new name in the data dict. But I can't make this work except by copying the src file to a temp dir with the desired name and uploading that.  It's a bit of a hack, but it works.

good luck, 
Mike

Comment: Mike, thanks for your input! I looked at what you did and actually made it work for my specific case. Since you mentioned that you weren't able to solve the renaming, I took some time and solved that issue as well. I made sure to make it a put call and not post. It now renames the file to the appropriate name right away!

Comment: Very good that it worked for you.  I'll try the put and see if I can make that work.

Comment: Just an aside: I found those 1 character variables hard to read. "ff", "fn", "fol", "ret", "ufiles", "folid" also don't give me much information...

Answer (score 0):

My solution, using requests:

```
def upload_to_box(folder_id, auth_token, file_out):
    headers = { 'Authorization' : BOX_AUTH.format(auth_token) }
    url = 'https://api.box.com/2.0/files/content'
    files = { 'filename': (new_file_name, open(file_out,'rb')) }
    data = { 'folder_id': folder_id }
    response = requests.post(url, params=data, files=files, headers=headers)
```

It would be nice if you could specify the `new_copy` parameter but there's nothing documented for it and it doesn't seem to work.