# transpose curl PUT to requests.put

Tags: python, curl, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I would like to transpose the curl command (which upload a local file to rackspace)

```
curl -X PUT -T screenies/hello.jpg -D - \
-H "X-Auth-Token: fc81aaa6-98a1-9ab0-94ba-aba9a89aa9ae" \
https://storage101.dfw1.clouddrive.com/v1/CF_xer7_343/images/hello.jpg
```

to python requests. So far I have:

```
url = 'http://storage.clouddrive.com/v1/CF_xer7_343/images/hello.jpg'
headers = {'X-Auth-Token': 'fc81aaa6-98a1-9ab0-94ba-aba9a89aa9ae'}
request = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data={})
```

where do I specify I want to upload `screenies/hello.jpg`?

I understand `-T` in curl represents 'to FTP server', but I have searched the [requests's github](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) but cannot find mention of FTP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569545/upload-file-using-python-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `-T` just means 'upload this file', which *can* be used with FTP but is not limited to that.

You can just upload the file data as the `data` parameter:

```
with open('screenies/hello.jpg', 'rb') as image:
    request = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=image)
```

where `data` will read and upload the image data for you.